# What counts towards the Host badges?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In **Animal Crossing: New Leaf,** everyone is well aware that **Phineas**, the **scoutmaster**, hands out badges when you've achieved something. Well, I am having difficulty understanding the qualifications. I don't understand 2 of them, but I'll ask about the other in a different question. Anyway, it is about the *Host* Badge. From reading the description of how to get the badge on [The Animal Crossing Wiki](http://www.animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Badge), I apparently need to host/invite 50 people to my town. The problem is, do I need to invite **50 different people** or can I invite a person **50 different times** and still get the badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some googling and checking [a number](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/post/40240706058/animal-crossing-new-leaf-badges-guide) [of sources](http://www.animalcrossingcommunity.com/Topic/6045712/1/Question_about_the_Good_Host_Badge) [for confirmation](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/answers?qid=354608), the Host badges can be obtained from the same person visiting your town several times, **or** several people visiting you once. Even some combination of the two, so long as the total visits is 50 (for bronze. 200 for silver, 500 for gold). Similarly, you can get the traveling badges by going to the same place over and over.

Comment: but can it also be me inviting 50 different people?

Comment: Per the links; "*can* be the same person/village" "it's the total visits not who visits". It only matters that you are visited 50 times, not who visits you.